# Js: How can i convert an Object property name to a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to iterate through an object and get the property names so i can use them to retrieve a localstored item.

```
for (var property in parts) {
  if (parts.hasOwnProperty(property)) {


    var item = localStorage.getItem(property);

    console.log(item);
  }
}
```

how can i achieve this ?

Comment: Looks like you already are ?

Comment: Property names are already strings. What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @slebetman  my bad, i think it was an error in the code, it was returning null. this was due to me setting the local storage wrongly

Comment: @Sushanth my bad, i think it was an error in the code, it was returning null. this was due to me setting the local storage wrongly

Answer (score 0):

You can get all object keys as array of strings via `Object.keys(object)`, and then iterate through this array with any iteration method for arrays, for example, let's use `forEach`:

```js
const obj = {
  one: true,
  two: 2,
  three: 'Value three'
}
const keys = Object.keys(obj);
keys.forEach(key => {
  console.log('Current key:', key);
  //const item = localStorage.getItem(key);
})
```

Comment: @FelixKling, right, OP's way is totally correct, I've just hurried to answer). My answer as more like an alternative way, may be someone will find it useful